# SVM gives worse success rate than KNN - Matlab

Tags: pca, svm, matlab

I am using PCA with a SVM classifier to classify the image.

```
SVMModel = fitcecoc(projectimg', train_label);
```

I have 40 subjects, each with 5 features (= total of 200 images).

I therefore have the "train_label" matrix as
[1;1;1;1;1;2;2;2;2;2;3;3;3;3;3;4;4;4;4;4;5...40;40;40;40;40]

1. I got the projected images down to a 200 x 200 matrix using the PCA analysis - **"projectimg"**.
2. I then used the following command to "Train" the SVM classifier:

   SVMModel = fitcecoc(projectimg', train_label);
3. I then generated the projected test image, - **"projtestimg"**.

I now wanted to classify this test image, so I use the following command:

```
[label score] = predict(SVMModel,projtestimg');
```

After running this classify for different test images in the data base, I get a success rate of 82.5% compared to 87.5% with the PCA-KNN test.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong?  I am using the value from the "label" to be used as the classified image.  Is this correct?  Thanks for your time.

Comment: is your svm linear?

Comment: I am assuming that the svm is not linear.  I also tried the commands  `t = templateSVM('KernelFunction','gaussian');  SVMModel = fitcecoc(projectimg', train_label,'Learners',t);`, but got about the same result.  Thanks for your time and help!